# Find number of "active" rows each month for multiple months in one query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a mySQL database with each row containing an activate and a deactivate date.  This refers to the period of time when the object the row represents was active.

```
activate     deactivate   id
2015-03-01   2015-05-10   1
2013-02-04   2014-08-23   2
```

I want to find the number of rows that were active at any time during each month.  Ex.

```
Jan: 4
Feb: 2
Mar: 1
etc...
```

I figured out how to do this for a single month, but I'm struggling with how to do it for all 12 months in a year in a single query.  The reason I would like it in a single query is for performance, as information is used immediately and caching wouldn't make sense in this scenario.  Here's the code I have for a month at a time.  It checks if the activate date comes before the end of the month in question and that the deactivate date was not before the beginning of the period in question.

```
SELECT * from tblName WHERE activate <= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
AND deactivate >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 2 MONTH)
```

If anybody has any idea how to change this and do grouping such that I can do this for an indefinite number of months I'd appreciate it.  I'm at a loss as to how to group.

Comment: in your sample Id=1 was active for months 3,4 and 5? so will add in all three months? same Id=2 will add on (2,3,4,5,6,7,8)

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza Yes, I want to know how many rows are active in each month, so items that are active for multiple months will be counted towards each month's count.

Comment: I think Gordon already give you the answer. If you need anything else just add another comment.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a table of months that you care about, you can do:

```
select m.*,
       (select count(*)
        from table t
        where t.activate_date <= m.month_end and
              t.deactivate_date >= m.month_start
       ) as Actives
from months m;
```

If you don't have such a table handy, you can create one on the fly:

```
select m.*,
       (select count(*)
        from table t
        where t.activate_date <= m.month_end and
              t.deactivate_date >= m.month_start
       ) as Actives
from (select date('2015-01-01') as month_start, date('2015-01-31') as month_end union all
      select date('2015-02-01') as month_start, date('2015-02-28') as month_end union all
      select date('2015-03-01') as month_start, date('2015-03-31') as month_end union all
      select date('2015-04-01') as month_start, date('2015-04-30') as month_end
     ) m;
```

EDIT:

A potentially faster way is to calculate a cumulative sum of activations and deactivations and then take the maximum per month:

```
select year(date), month(date), max(cumes)
from (select d, (@s := @s + inc) as cumes
      from (select activate_date as d, 1 as inc from table t union all
            select deactivate_date, -1 as inc from table t
           ) t cross join
           (select @s := 0) param
      order by d
     ) s
group by year(date), month(date);
```

Comment: It works but takes 12 seconds to run on our production server.  I'm going to try to find a faster way.